# Error al recuperar dato mediante función Python desde formulario HTML post

Tags: python, django

Me devuelve error al querer recuperar el dato value, que como se ve en el ejemplo debería llegar el valor 123. A la función def simple_function sí que llega, pero una vez ahí no consigo recuperar el valor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

views.py

```
def simple_function(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        id = request.form['tagValue']
        print(id)
```

template.html

```
<form class="" action="{% url 'scada_app:simple_function' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" id="tagValue" name="tagValue" value="123">
    <button class="form-control btn-success mb-5" type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSgae.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSgae.png) tengo este error no entiendo a que se debe
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzxWu.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzxWu.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambia esta línea:

```
id = request.form['tagValue']
```

por esta:

```
id = request.POST.get('tagValue')
```

Comment: Podrías aclarar por que hacer ese cambio solucionaría el problema del OP por favor? De ese modo aumentarás la calidad de tu respuesta, la comunidad la recibirá mejor y tanto el OP como personas con el mismo problema en el futuro podrán aprender algo nuevo.

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir con "op"? Saludos